# Send audio with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, share

I'm tring to send an audio file to other apps.

If I only provide the file url, I can send to AirDrop, mail and message app

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:file];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[url];

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

// Present the controller
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I add the file name to the object to share I can also send it to clipboard

```
...
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[@"filename.m4a", url];
...
```

But how can I send it the other application accepting audio file?
For example my application accepts "public.audio" and is listed by other apps that send audio files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For opening a file in another app you should use the [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html); its [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403) might be helpful too